# Can a transaction be conditioned on signing another transaction?

Tags: transactions, script

I was thinking around http://lightning.network/ .

My problem is Alice sending coins to Bob via Eve: `A -- tx1 -> E -- tx2 -> B`

Is there a way to condition tx1 on Eve signing tx2?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you could do something similar by combining tx1 and tx2 into a single transaction.

So, instead of:

> tx1:
>
> ```
> Input         | Output
> Alice (1 BTC) | Eve (1 BTC)
> ```
>
> tx2:
>
> ```
> Input          | Output
> Eve (0.99 BTC) | Bob (0.99 BTC)
> ```

you could use:

> tx:
>
> ```
> Input          | Output
> Alice (1 BTC)  | Eve (0.01 BTC)
>                | Bob (0.99 BTC)
> ```

This doesn't seem useful for the lightning network, because you really don't want to have a payment fail just because a settlement somewhere along the path failed.

Comment: You do though, I mean you want either complete failure or complete success. In case something along the chain fails then everyone can go back to their previous state (as these transactions haven't been published yet).

Comment: Further question: Can you have input from 2 multisig addresses and it will only be valid once everyone signs it? For example input (Alice+Eve and Eve+Bob) will only become valid once all 3 of them sign it?